ServiceAPIController No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
In SC 10.1.3, we are trying to access a Controller inherited from ServiceAPIController, but receiving a NO HTTP Resource Found error.
We introduced the config and controller as below
<processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers, Sitecore.Kernel']"
 
          type="testapi.Register.RegisterApiRoute, testapi" />

[ServicesController]
    public class CommonApiController : ServicesApiController
    {
        public CommonApiController() { }
 
        [Route("goto/xxx")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage xxx()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }

When we try to request https://domain/goto/xxx we receive the following error message

NO HTTP Resource Found

App is not able to find the controller. What is wrong in our setup?

You need to register your route first like below:
public class RegisterHttpRoutes
{
  public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
  {
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Configure);
  }
 
  protected void Configure(HttpConfiguration configuration)
  {
    var routes = configuration.Routes;
    routes.MapHttpRoute("CommentApi", "sitecore/api/comments/{id}", new
    {
      controller = "CommentApi",
      action = "Get"
    });
  }
}

Then you need to patch your processor initialize pipeline:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers, Sitecore.Kernel']"
          type="LaubPlusCo.Examples.RegisterHttpRoutes, LaubPlusCo.Examples" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Below is a code of API Controller:
public class CommentApiController : ServicesApiController
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
  {
    var comment = new Comment
    {
      Id = ID.NewID.ToGuid(),
      Name = "Test Person",
      Email = "mailme@testperson.dk",
      Subject = "I have a comment",
      CommentMessage = "This is my comment"
    };
    return new JsonResult<Comment>(comment, new JsonSerializerSettings(), Encoding.UTF8, this);
  }
}

You can try to call API via PostMan first.

Check if you have configure route like below. Register your route with MapHttpRoute instead of MapRoute For example
public class RegisterApiRoute
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        Configure(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected void Configure(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapHttpRoute("botroutes", "api/commonapi", new
        {
            controller = "CommonApi",
            action = "xxx"
        });
    }
}

Hope this will work.

You may need to add a RoutePrefix attribute or ensure that the global routing configuration is set up to recognize your routes.
The processor configuration should be correctly placed in the appropriate configuration file, typically App_Config\Include\z.ProjectName\projectname.config.
Processor Configuration
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="testapi.Register.RegisterApiRoute, testapi" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Route Registration
You need to ensure the route is registered correctly. Here's an example of how to do this in the RegisterApiRoute class:
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace testapi.Register
{
    public class RegisterApiRoute
    {
        public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "CommonApi",
                routeTemplate: "goto/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "CommonApi" }
            );
        }
    }
}

Ensure that the controller is set up correctly. The ServicesController attribute might need to be RoutePrefix
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace testapi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("goto")]
    public class CommonApiController : ApiController
    {
        public CommonApiController() { }

        [Route("xyz")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Xyz()
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "test");
        }
    }
}


Can you check that you have properly registered your Controller. We had faced this issue and for us the registration of the controller was an issue.
Also in your Question, I can clearly see that you have mentioned App is not able to find the controller for which the below solution should be helpful.
Example
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;

namespace Demo
{
    public class RegisterDependencies : IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(CommonApiController));
        }
    }
}

After this you need to register it in available services through a patch config file
Example
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:env="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/env/">
  <sitecore>
    <services>
      <configurator type="Demo.RegisterDependencies, Demo" />
    </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Hope this will be helpful to you!

In order to register Service Api controller, you need to register the route as below using MapHttpRoute function.
using Sitecore.Pipelines;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class RegisterServiceRoutes
{
     public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
     {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
     }
     protected virtual void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
     {
        routes.MapHttpRoute("comments", "api/comments/{action}", new
        {
           controller = "Comments",
           action = "Get"
        });
     }
}

Thereafter, add the above route registration processor inside the initialize pipeline to register routes.
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
      <pipelines>
         <initialize>
                <processor type="SitecoreCustomExtensions.Pipelines.RegisterServiceRoutes,SitecoreCustomExtensions" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']"/>
         </initialize>
      </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>

Once above configuration is done, Service Api controller needs to be created as below.
using Sitecore.Services.Core;
using Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

[ServicesController]
public class CommentsController : ServicesApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   public HttpResponseMessage Get()
   {
      HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
      response.Content = new StringContent("Get Method Call");
      return response;
   }

   [ActionName("fetch")]
   [HttpGet]
   public HttpResponseMessage Fetch()
   {
      HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
      response.Content = new StringContent("Fetch Method Call");
      return response;
   }
}

Since in the above route registration Get is the default method when action is not specified, hence call to below url's returns following output.

api/comments -> Returns output as Get Method Call
api/comments/fetch -> Returns output as Fetch Method Call

Note: Make sure you are using System.Web.Http namespace for action verbs while using Service Api controller.
Using above way, you can successfully configure the Service Api controller inside Sitecore.
Update
Created the blog onto how to add API's using Service API controller in Sitecore as below.
https://sitecorefoundation.in/2024/07/21/deep-dive-into-sitecore-services-api-controller/
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any doubts.

@sylesh Created the blog that covers the complete insights onto Service API controller in Sitecore. Added the details for the same above. Hope this helps!!!
